# RJ11 hardware for Raspberry Pi (RasPBX)

Tags: hardware

I'm trying to build an IVR system using Raspberry Pi. See following diagram

[image]

I'm not sure which hardware to use for blue and green boxes.

For the blue box maximum number of phones will be 3. They are just normal phones not IP phones. It should work on both ways.

When dialing into the phone number it will play a message and based on user selection (ivr) call will forward to a one of the connected telephones. If user pressed 1 call will goto only "Telephone 1" ect.

Also when someone dialed from "Telephone 1" it should go thru raspberry pi as a normal call.

Can someone suggest hardware (adapter?) to archive this.

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't get the answers you need here, you might try the forums for [asterisk](https://www.asterisk.org) and/or [FreePBX](https://www.freepbx.org/). There's even a website devoted to [Asterisk-on-Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberry-asterisk.org/) that has a [forum on SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/p/raspbx/discussion/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, it's not a good idea to put the provider link to an unofficial device. They've been checking the current that phones are using and it's easy to figure out you are using an unauthorized or an unofficial device then you may be warned by them.

However, to solve this problem, you should put the provider link to a phone and get an output link from the phone.

> I'm not sure which hardware to use for blue and green boxes.

It's possible to make it happened by an "RS232 56K Modem Modules". You just need to find one that could connect to the RPi by `USB` port like [THIS](http://www.radi.com/modular41.htm).
You have to manage four `USB` input by your purpose.

Also, I think you can do it without a "Modulator/Demodulator" modem.

In addition,[This link](http://renogy.boards.net/thread/535/using-rj12-cable-connect-raspberry) would be helpful.

Comment: By mistake, I lost **100 reputation** for setting bounty for this post. It was my question too and I've searched a lot then find these findings. If it could, upvote.

Comment: Unless someone provides an answer that gets more score I think you will get the bounty in the end.

Comment: @goldilocks I asked a question, unfortunately, it's impossible.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341246/can-i-get-back-the-reputation-of-a-bounty-if-the-author-accepts-my-answer